# Parentheses after function call

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and I am reading this code.

I understand the first `val bucketizers` is a function as variable, and `val newCols` called the `bucketizers`.

However, I do not understand why in `bucketizers(idx)(filteredDataset(inputCol).cast(DoubleType))` we have a parentheses after a function call `bucketizers(idx)`. I checked a few advanced topics, including closure, high-order function, and chain function call, but I do not think I find my answer.

Questions: What are this parentheses called? Can we rewritten it in another way?

Code:

```
val bucketizers: Seq[UserDefinedFunction] = seqOfSplits.zipWithIndex.map { case (splits, idx) =>
      udf { (feature: Double) =>
        Bucketizer.binarySearchForBuckets(splits, feature, keepInvalid)
      }.withName(s"bucketizer_$idx")
    }


    val newCols = inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map { case (inputCol, idx) =>
      bucketizers(idx)(filteredDataset(inputCol).cast(DoubleType))
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use the word "parentless" repeatedly? Who is parentless? I've seen a few higher-order functions and closures, they all grew up in large happy families, none of them were "parentless". The title is strange in a sad and weird way.

Comment: I meant parentheses :P

Comment: yeah, seriously, thank you for fixing that title, it looked really kind of strange&sad ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step by step:

- The variable `bucketizers` holds a sequence of type `Seq[UserDefinedFunction]`.
- Therefore, for each index `idx: Int`, the expression
  `bucketizers(idx)` is a `UserDefinedFunction`
- If `f` is a `UserDefinedFunction`, and `x` is a suitable argument, then you can call the function passing `x` as argument as follows: `f(x)`.
- For example, you can call `bucketizers(idx)(x)` with `x = filteredDataset(inputCol).cast(DoubleType)`

Here again all pieces together as ASCII-art:

```
bucketizers(idx)(filteredDataset(inputCol).cast(DoubleType))
\______________/^\________________________________________/^
  function      |               argument                   |
                |                                          |
           open parens for argument                   close parens
```

---

Here is a toy example that uses nothing but the basic syntax:

```
val inputColumns = List(
  List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),   // first "column"
  List(4, 6, 5, 7, 12, 15)  // second "column"
)

type UDF = Function[List[Int], List[Int]]

val bucketizers: Seq[UDF] = List(
  _.map(_ * 42),              // first "UDF"
  _.map(_  % 3)               // second "UDF"
)

println(bucketizers(0)(List(1, 100))) // 42, 4200
println(bucketizers(1)(List(1,2,3,4))) // 1,2,0,1

val modifiedTable = inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map{ case (col, idx) =>
  bucketizers(idx)(col)
}

println(modifiedTable)
// Output:
// List(
//   List(42, 84, 126, 168, 210, 252), // first column times 42
//   List(1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0)            // second column modulo 3
// )
```

Here, we declare a "table" with two columns, and a list of functions. Then we apply each function to the corresponding column.

Answer (score 1):

bucketizers is a Seq of function, as the name suggests.

This is a very simplified pattern of what is going on:

```
scala> val f1 = (i: Int) => 2 * i
f1: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val f2 = (i: Int) => 3 + i
f2: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val funs: Seq[Function1[Int,Int]] = Seq (f1, f2)
funs: Seq[Int => Int] = List(<function1>, <function1>)

scala> (0 to 1).map (idx=> 
       funs(idx) (Math.max (7, 8)))
res74: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(16, 11)
```

In the collection funs, the one with index idx is called. The parameterlist is, what follows.

Comment: Great! In this case, `seqOfSplits.zipWithIndex` implicit declared the whole parameter list?

Comment: No, in this case it is explicit. :) Implicit declaration is always with the keyword `implicit`. val bucketizers = ... is a value definition. That code already executed and created a Seq[UserDefinedFunction] ... - ah, a moment please - I am wrong, idx is here an index into the Seq. Will delete my wrong post. Sorry.